# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: android GCM token generation crash

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

App is getting crashed after launch throwing following error if we put GCM sender id in airshipconfig.properties file used in case of urban airship pushnotification.

Error:

**java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)**

gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {

        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }

    maven { url "https://urbanairship.bintray.com/android" }

    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.samachar.newskannada"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField 'String', 'CONTAINER_ID', '"containedid"'  //Development
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'GTM_VERBOSE_ENABLE', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'APP_KEY', '"appkey"'
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField 'String', 'CONTAINER_ID', '"GTM_id"'  //Development
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'GTM_VERBOSE_ENABLE', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'APP_KEY', '"appkey"'
            //progard
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
    // Urban Airship SDK
    compile 'com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:7.0.+'
    // Recommended for in-app messaging
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    // Recommended for location services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':Volley')
    compile 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.0.2'
    compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
    compile "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1"
}
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error was the file created with [`File getFilesDir ()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()), returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with [`openFileOutput(String, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String,%20int)) are stored.

The returned path may change over time if the calling app is moved to an adopted storage device, so only relative paths should be persisted.

The `getNoBackupFilesDir` was found in `android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat`. Seems that the problem was that an old appcompat-v7 included in the project.

Try to download with the SDK manager the [*latest version of Android Support Library*](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html) and then follow the steps for [Adding libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html) with resources and add the library to your application project.